# mssql - one stored procedure vs multiple storedprocedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a situation where server side function (c#) should return different selects from different tables (t1,t2, ...) database but number and type of params are always the same.

There is a param `@Type` which determine a type of select should be returned.

Is it better to write a different stored procedure for each `@type` or write one stored procedure with `switch(@type)` in it ?

edit:
each select may be large about 2000 - 3000 characters

Comment: Just as a note - there may be cases where it is usefull to just use one stored procedures albeit the fact, that based on the parameter different tables are used to return the result set. We are using a stored procedure getProducts(@country="GB") that joins a product table with a price table. The price table is different based on the passed country. But since it is always products + prices we choose to use the same procedure to have it all in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only commonality between the stored procedure is the definition of the parameters, I can't see any reason to have them as one stored procedure.

One of the principles of software design is the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - you should aim to apply that general intention to your stored procedures